# Why is Bob a normal guy? Episode 2

Tags: wordplay

[We've already learned so much about Bob](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35048/why-is-bob-a-normal-guy), but here are 7 more facts about him:

1. He often enjoys moldy food with fermented drinks.
2. His favourite candy contains chicken bones.
3. He only gets ⅓ sleep per day, and that leaves him feeling refreshed.
4. None of his pencils contain lead.
5. 60% of his friends are water.
6. He's never far away from a chimpanzee.
7. His brain has barely grown since he was six years old.

Can you reinterpret each fact to make Bob sound like a pretty normal guy?

*Note that there are multiple possibilities, but one of each will do.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He often enjoys moldy food with fermented drinks.

> He likes eating cheese with wine
>
>  **OR**
>
>  his parents frequently make him tempeh for dinner, which he eats with homemade ginger ale (this will... make sense when you reach the end...)

His favourite candy contains chicken bones.

> He likes chewy candy which contains gelatin

He only gets ⅓ sleep per day, and that leaves him feeling refreshed.

> He sleeps ⅓ of the day, i.e., 8 hours

None of his pencils contain lead.

> Pencils these days write with graphite

60% of his friends are water.

> The human body is approximately 60% water by some estimates

He's never far away from a chimpanzee.

> His *DNA* is never that far from the *DNA* of a chimpanzee

His brain has barely grown since he was six years old.

> He turned seven last Tuesday. Regardless, by age six ([or slightly later](http://cercor.oxfordjournals.org/content/6/5/726.full.pdf)), "[the brain is already 95 percent of its adult size.](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/teenbrain/interviews/giedd.html)"

Comment: Don't ask how the first and last two make sense together: he has terrible parents and his friends are a bad influence.

Comment: Nice...last sentence verifies why he still uses pencil

Comment: There is a less surprising answer for the last fact if you were wondering

Comment: @rybo111 It wouldn't happen to be [along these lines](http://www.theurbanchildinstitute.org/sites/all/files/brain_growth_by_age.460x221.png)? In context I'm not sure I'd call the estimated ~5-10% "barely" regardless of how literally you mean "grown."

Comment: @Will 5-10% appears minimal in say 10 years compared to the first 6 years of development. I see your point though.

Comment: Happy to accept this answer. But curious to hear other possibilities as per the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i think could be the answer.

He often enjoys moldy food with fermented drinks.

> bob likes cheese and wine

His favorite candy contains chicken bones.

> his favorite candy is named chicken bones(look it up if you want to see for your self).

He only gets ⅓ sleep per day, and that leaves him feeling refreshed.

> Bob is sleeping one third of the day or about 7.5 hours which is normal.

None of his pencils contain lead.

> his pencils contain graphite.

60% of his friends are water.

> this is referring to the fact that everyone's bodies are 60% water

He's never far away from a chimpanzee.

> humans are a cousin to the chimpanzee.

His brain has barely grown since he was six years old.

> most of our brains growth happens during childhood after that its growth is very small.